# How do i add conversion tracking for magento community for adroll

Tags: php, magento, adroll

I am using magento 1.8.1.0 community edition and I have signed up with adroll retargeting service and need to add conversion tracking.The code adroll supplies to add (to success.phtml) is this :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
adroll_conversion_value_in_dollars = <?php echo $total ?>;
adroll_custom_data = {"ORDER_ID": "<?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?>"};
</script>
```

I have added it to the end of the file. This does not work and my rep says that it only works with Enterprise edition (I cant think why this would be). I have searched further and have been trying :

```
<?php
//Get Order Number & Order Total
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
?>

<script type = "text/javascript">
adroll_conversion_value_in_dollars = <?php echo $amount; ?>; //order total
adroll_custom_data = {"ORDER_ID": "<?php echo $this->getOrderId() ?>"};  //    Order Number
</script>
```

If i add a static conversion amount value via the adroll admin interface and try a test checkout then it registers the conversion and uses that static amount (so proving communication takes place). If I dont have a static amount then the conversion is not registered - so this suggests the actual value is not being passed?

Can anyone see if there is something wrong with that code or know how I can achieve this.

** UPDATE **

The above second set of code is working. The confusion was because when I relied on the static value only , it updated conversions immediately. When I removed on the static values and relied on the passing of the order value it takes some time to update in the backend (not sure why - maybe processed as a cron somehow) but my values are "arriving" some times afterwards now which is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: not sure why someone down voted that question for being unclear and showing no research effort  - care to comment please? -  as I think it is perfectly clear and shows I researched , added code I thought would work and found it to not work.It is also useful for anyone that has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a version difference, but in my `success.phtml` template I use `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId())`. May be worth a try.

Another option you could try is `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByAttribute('quote_id', Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId())`.

Comment: thanks for the answer - it has actually started to work now . I went for lunch and came back and some test orders had shown. Seems that there is some delay in updating the conversion amounts but it it is a static value in the backup only that seems to update almost instantly. I will keep an eye on it but it is definately passing values now so I will leave the code as is